# coffeescript sourcemap not loading in chrome

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node-inspector

I am able to compile coffee file to .map file in the same directory as the .coffee/.js file when I call

```
coffee --nodejs --debug-brk app.coffee
```

and start the node-inspector. The js version of the app file gets loaded in chrome. what am i missing??

this is what chrome is showing for three.coffee file ..

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
  app.get('/three', function(req, res) {
    debugger;    return res.send('three/teedde');
  });

}).call(this);

/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=three.map
*/

});
```

thanks

Comment: Have you configured chrome to enable source map?

Comment: yes. I switched on the enable source map..infact I went and deleted the app.js but still it shows app.coffee but it has .js code in it.

Comment: This might be related to an [issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2806) I raised.

Comment: were you able to debug the coffee file in chrome .

Comment: Are trying to debug a client or a server (node.js) app?

Comment: Looks like this a node-inspector issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And now node-inspector supports source maps!
>   github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/… –  Vitaliy Lebedev
>   Nov 8 '13 at 12:46

Answer (score 2):

You are you asking about node-inspector since you say you are starting it? Your question appears as if you are asking about the Chrome dev tools. Please clarify.

<del>The current version of node-inspector in npm (0.2.0beta4) does not support source maps.</del>

<del>Even though the [issue](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/issues/100) has been closed, I have been unable to find anything on github that would enable this feature (e.g. see https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/blob/update-ui/lib/session2.js#L123-L131, there is no sourceMapURL parameter for the scriptParsed event).</del>

node-inspector was taken over by a new developer and according to a comment (by Vitaliy Lebedev) the latest version does support source maps.

---

If you are asking about the Chrome dev tools - [they support source maps](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/source-maps-101/).

try "//@ sourceMappingURL=three.map" on the last line in your js file.

Also make sure that your express app is actually serving the .map and .coffee files required by the debugger (check by entering the url+filename in your browser).

Comment: I know chrome supports source maps and I am able to do that for coffee script on a webpage. I am talking about the nodejs/express app written in cofffeescript and debugging it. I am pretty sure I am missing something because now that coffeescript is generating source maps ..chrome should be able to pick it as it doing on a web page.

Comment: Are you serving map and coffee files? See my last comment.

Comment: what do you mean by serving. chrome picks up the js files by itself..so it should pickup the coffee file as well..

Comment: Yes but to get to chrome your map and coffee files need to be on the server and your express app needs to serve (send) them.

Comment: I don't know what you need to serve them, but both the js and coffee and map files are in the same directory..has any one tried debugging nodejs coffeescript in node-inspector ????

Comment: You are confusing node-inspector with the Chrome dev tools. They may look similar but node-inspector does not yet support maps - see the first part in my answer.

Comment: ok then, the question is how do I debug expressjs app on chrome dev tool without the node-inspector.

Comment: Chrome does not support that. The only alternative is AFAIK http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27896/discussion-between-coool-and-chris)

Comment: And now node-inspector supports source maps! https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/100#issuecomment-21503952